# get some parameters to selected item in typeahead bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Twitter bootstrap and I use its typeahead 
I used this code :

```
$('#demo1').typeahead({
    source:[
        { id: 1, name: 'Toronto' ,country: 'usa'},
        { id: 2, name: 'Montreal',country: 'china' },
        { id: 3, name: 'New York',country: 'usa' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Buffalo' ,country: 'china'},
        { id: 5, name: 'Boston' ,country: 'usa'},
        { id: 6, name: 'Columbus',country: 'china' },
        { id: 7, name: 'Dallas'  ,country: 'italy'},
        { id: 8, name: 'Vancouver' ,country: 'turky'},
        { id: 9, name: 'Seattle'  ,country: 'france'},
        { id: 10, name: 'Los Angeles' ,country: 'usa'}
    ],
    itemSelected: displayRes
});
```

and this is `displayRes` function

```
function displayRes(item, val,text) {
    console.log(val);
    console.log(text);
    $('#demo1').val('');
}
```

when I get in the console **val** : is the id of selected item & **text**: is the name of selected item

but how can I get the **country** in the function `displayRes` ?

Comment: There are a few different third-party typeahead libraries for Bootstrap v3, please link to the specific one that you're using.

Comment: this is a link for the typeahead library file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ogvn3qvuh22jw1/bootstrap-typeahead.js?dl=0

Comment: Okay, so you mean https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead . Looks like it doesn't support Bootstrap v3.

Comment: yes, what should I do ?

Comment: Use https://github.com/bassjobsen/typeahead.js-bootstrap-css and Typeahead.js instead?